# ASP.net listview with tree like outlook

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview, datagrid, outlook

I'd like to make a page that shows list, something like inbox in outlook 2003. Specifically i need to group messages by day or week, and show a tree for each day (or week). Using asp.net. Hope you help me. The following pictures shows what I need: grouping mails by date:

http://www.omni-ts.com/crm-integration/images/riva-outlook-inbox.jpg

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this tutorial. I think it describes exactly what you need if you focus on the ListView part, not the LINQ to SQL part. It does not realy matter where you get your data from.

http://mattberseth.com/blog/2008/01/building_a_grouping_grid_with.html

Regards,
Gerald

Answer (score 1):

Are you wanting to do this client side?

If so maybe take a look at a javascript library called dynatree.

I used this to create a folder structure that i could navigate through so you can probably customise it to suit your needs.

Comment: It seems it's what I need. Going to check it out. Other solutions are welcome.

Comment: Glad I could be of help. Did you decide to go with this option in the end? Or was it not suitable?

Comment: I couldn't do it yet, i'll try it if i don't reach the project dead line.

Comment: Did you get this working in the end or did you run out of time?